# Understanding access of object attributes in Powershell scripting

Tags: regex, powershell, oop

Firstly I'm trying to understand this. Second I would like to use it.

```
 # test string
$pgNumString = 'C:\test\test5\AALTONEN-ALLAN_PENCARROW_PAGE_1.txt'

# Regex with capture group for number '1' ONLY from $pgNumString
# In other use cases it may be page 10 or any page in 100s
$pgNumRegex = "(?s)_(\d+)\."

# Simplest - not using -SimpleMatch because this example uses regex (Select-String docs)
$pgNum = $pgNumString | Select-String -Pattern $pgNumRegex -AllMatches
```

The match is not assigned to `$pgNum`. No capture grouping means no good anyway. A slightly more sophisticated attempt:

```
$pgNum = $pgNumString | Select-String -Pattern $pgNumRegex -AllMatches | Select-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

Output:

```
$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
--------------------------
1
```

The match is still not assigned to `$pgNum`. But the output shows I'm on the right track. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `Select-Object` to `ForEach-Object`

Comment: Yes Santiago. Thank you. `ForEach-Object` gives me the correct output.

Comment: @Dave, something I didn't spell out in my answer: you only need `-AllMatches` if there can be multiple matches _per input string_.
That is, if you feed text _line by line_ to `Select-String` (as happens when you pass a file path to `-Path` / `-LiteralPath`, for instance, or provide input via `Get-Content` _without using `-Raw`_)
and you only ever expect at most _one_ match _per line_, you do _not_ need `-AllMatches`.
In cases where you do need `-AllMatches`, `$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value` is _not_ sufficient to extract all matches, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially if you're dealing with **strings already in memory**, but often also with files (except if they're exceptionally large), **use of [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) isn't necessary** and both slows down and complicates the solution, as your example shows.

While **[`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch)** works in principle too - to focus on matching only what should be extracted - it is **limited to  *one* match**, whose results are reflected in the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches).

However, you can make direct use of an underlying .NET API, namely **[`[regex]::Matches()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches)**.

```bash
# Sample input.
$pgNumString = @'
C:\test\test5\AALTONEN-ALLAN_PENCARROW_PAGE_1.txt
C:\test\test6\AALTONEN-ALLAN_PENCARROW_PAGE_42.txt
'@

# -> '1', '42'
# Note: To match PowerShell's case-*insensitive* behavior (not relevant here), use:
#  [regex]::Matches($pgNumString, '(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)', 'IgnoreCase').Value
[regex]::Matches($pgNumString, '(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)').Value
```

As an aside:

- Bringing the functionality of `[regex]::MatchAll()` natively to PowerShell in the future, in the form of a `-matchall` operator, is the subject of [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867).

Note that I've modified your regex to use *look-around assertions* so that what it captures consists solely of the substring to extract, reflected in the `.Value` property.
For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/BEYQ1S/1).

Using your original approach requires extra work to extract the capture-group values, with the help of the [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach):

```bash
[regex]::Matches($pgNumString, '_(\d+)\.').ForEach({ $_.Groups[1].Value })
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

As Santiago notes, you need to use `ForEach-Object` instead of `Select-Object`, but there's an additional requirement:

Given your use of `-AllMatches`, you need to access `.Groups[1].Value` on *each* of the matches reported in `.Matches`, otherwise you'll only get the *first* match's capture-group value:

```bash
$pgNumString | 
  Select-String -Pattern $pgNumRegex -AllMatches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.ForEach({ $_.Groups[1].Value }) }
```

As an aside:

- Making `Select-String` only return the matching parts of the input lines / strings, via an `-OnlyMatching` switch is a green-lit future enhancement - see [GitHub issue #7712](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7712)
- While this wouldn't directly help with *capture groups*, it is usually possible to reformulate regexes with look-around assertions, as shown with `[regex]::Matches()` above.

Comment: Thank you mklement0. A lot to unpack here.